# Is there a way to reference (or use reflection) on a NET 5 class library in a Source Generator (NET 2 standard)

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0, sourcegenerators

I'm writing a source generator that needs to look at types, type names, and their properties within another project.

Unfortunately, source generator projects have to target NET Standard 2.0 and the class library project that it needs to look at to generate code is NET 5.  Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: That's an unusual requirement, I think.  Can you explain a bit more the concrete scenario you are facing?  What is in the class library that you want to interrorgate, for example? What is the nature of the source file in the project using the source generator?  Possibly there are other ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm actually trying to leverage source generators (perhaps this isn't the best use case for them) to create some code for unit tests.  I have a NET 5 Domain class library and want to create some custom object builders from it for a Unit Tests project.  Basically, I have the rough template for these desired output classes (which I want saved to disk) but I'm still working on the mechanism on how these class files are created.  Worst case I hack it and create a console program to do it -- but I'd like some tooling that feels a little more "built-in".

Comment: @twistedbitandroid oh, so all the projects are in the same solution then?  And presumably the test project is referencing the domain project?  That's no problem at all, and the fact that your source generator is compiled with NET Standard is irrelevent.  If you show some code it'll be easier to help you, but if you have a handle to the `Compilation`, you can call `GetTypeByMetadataName("Your.Namespace.ClassName")` and do what you like with the information returned.